# dynamic indentation of li tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to indent my list tags dynamically as it can be tedious doing it in CSS, so I thought it can be done in jQuery instead.

How can this be achieved?

I have this big `ul li` nested tags and trying to indent this html although it can be just a single `ul li` tag.

```
<ul>
  <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
  <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>/li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<div id="student">
  <h3>Names</h3>
  <li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>skjut in mig!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>skjut in mig!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>skjut in mig!</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <p>mmm dolor</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <p>mmm ipsum dolor</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>skjut in mig!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>skjut in mig!</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</li>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("li").each(function() { 
  $(this).css("padding-left": 20);
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/02gEREBDc8cwSGvepKha?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain why not do this in css?

Comment: Which is the hard part on css https://plnkr.co/edit/LKfT7D3QdH91hJPN4hxj?p=preview ...

Comment: because its not a static values, `li` is just to wrap the data coming from an ajax call and data can be big.

Comment: It doesn't matter. CSS will be applied there...

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is indent everything in that's in an li tag, no need to use jquery, you can indent them all through css pretty easily.

```
li {
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: got a vote from me here :) css is the right solution here, not jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Your specific problem in your code is syntax error.

Chance this:

```
$(this).css("padding-left": 20);
```

To this:

```
$(this).css("padding-left", 20);
```

Or

```
$(this).css({"padding-left": 20});
```

However I really don't think that jquery is the solution here. You **should use** CSS for that (check the answer by @borbesaur).

Comment: Got a vote from me too.  Good to have answers that compliment each other.